# Peculiar features of I2C communication between RPi and Arduino

Tags: i2c, arduino, communication

I am currently trying to establish two-way communications between an Arduino Leonardo and a Pi model B using the I2C bus, as slave and master respectively. Spookily, the Pi can successfully send commands *to* the Arduino, but fails when requesting data from the Arduino. Spcifically, `smbus2` throws `OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error` whenever I call the `moisture_read()` function. The included `water()` function has the intended outcome -- the Arduino reacts and alters its pins (more or less) correctly.

Arduino Code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

#define SOILPWR 11
#define SOILSIG A0

#define MOTORPWR 5
#define MOTORDTEC A1

#define BUFSIZE 16

#define CHANNEL 0x03

int readMoisture(byte power, word dlay){
    analogWrite(SOILPWR,power);
    delay(dlay);
    int moisture = analogRead(A0);
    analogWrite(SOILPWR,0);
    return moisture;
}

void motorPulse(byte power, word dlay){
    // Motor is active low
    analogWrite(MOTORPWR,255-power);
    delay(dlay);
    analogWrite(MOTORPWR,255);
    delay(1000);
}

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(SOILSIG, INPUT);
    pinMode(SOILPWR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MOTORPWR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MOTORDTEC, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(MOTORPWR, HIGH);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
    Wire.begin(CHANNEL);
    #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.begin(9600);
    #endif
}

// BYTE STRUCTURE:
// ['S'][speed][time_LSB][time_HSB]

void receiveEvent(int nbytes){
    byte msg[nbytes];
    for (int i=0;i<nbytes;i++){
        msg[i]=Wire.read();
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print("Message:");
    for (int i=0;i<nbytes;i++){
        Serial.print(msg[i]);
        Serial.print('\n');
    }
    Serial.println();
    #endif

    byte b=msg[0];
    if (nbytes >= 4 && b == 'S'){
        // S for [S]oak
        // look I don't know why it's like this
        byte fast = msg[1];
        word t = msg[2] + (word) msg[3] << 8;

        #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print("Time: ");
        Serial.println(t);
        #endif

        // Limit watering to 1 minute
        t = t < 60000 ? t : 60000;

        motorPulse(fast,t);

    } else {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        #endif
    }

}

byte sendbuf[BUFSIZE];

// BYTE STRUCTURE
// [soil_LSB][soil_MSB][0][0]

void requestEvent(){
    int moisture = readMoisture(255, 200);
    sendbuf[0] = moisture&0x0f;
    sendbuf[1] = moisture&0xf0;
    for (int i=2; i<BUFSIZE;i++){
        sendbuf[i]=0x00;
    }
    Wire.write(sendbuf, 4);
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
}
```

Pi Code:

```py
import smbus2
import struct
import time

CHANNEL = 0x03
# Bus number is 1
bus = smbus2.SMBus(1)

def water(speed, time):
    req_str  = struct.pack('>B',speed)
    req_str += struct.pack('<H',1024*time)
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(CHANNEL, ord('S'), req_str)

def moisture_read():
    # read a block of 4 bytes (offset 0)
    res = bus.read_i2c_block_data(CHANNEL, 0, 4)
    return struct.unpack('<HBB',res)
```

Comment: SMBus is not I2C, similar but not the same.  I'd try just reading four bytes rather than what SMBus does of write register (restart) read four bytes.

Comment: That throws the same error. All of `read_byte_data`, `read_byte` and `read_i2c_block_data` fail with the same (rather unhelpful) message.

Comment: Okay.  I suggest you experiment with i2cget/i2cput (I think they are in i2c-tools).  That'll be quicker than editing/running a Python program.  If that doesn't help try my [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html).  `sudo pigpiod`  `pigs i2co 1 x 0` where x is the Arduino address and then use `pigs i2crd 0 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, my solution was to work around the problem entirely. I read rumors on other questions that the smbus read_i2c_block_data doesn't actually work, and so I rewrote the code such that the Arduino only ever sends one byte at a time (imitating the behaviour of a register on a basic I2C chip).

The final code can be found at https://github.com/Spuriosity1/basilbot.

The basic idea was:

- Store an array of bytes `byte buf[16]` that contains all relevant data and an index `byte idx`
- RPI writes a command to set `idx` (with range protection for safety)
- RPI requests from slave, which sends `buf[idx]`.